# What is the exact behavior of Catalina verifying app?

Tags: catalina, sip, gatekeeper, notarization

By 'verifying' I mean either

- an explicit popup of 'Verifying'
- or app launch stuck with `XProtectService` comsuming CPU in background

What I know

- An app on local drive with `com.apple.quarantine` xattr will be verified on the first start, or after something changed in the app.

However I found some app on without the xattr will still be verified, especially app copied from (or directly run on) an external/network drive.

- What is the exact behavior?
- Anyway to avoid this (without fully disable SIP)?

Comment: "Anyway to avoid this (without fully disable SIP)?" Turn off Gatekeeper.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure that anyone knows the full extent of how Apple’s protections work, but if I wanted to understand them better, I would start by reading Howard Oakley’s site at http://eclecticlight.co as he has done the most thorough job writing about it.

I know SE likes answers that aren’t just links, but there's way too much to try to summarize here.

This would be a good place to start reading: https://eclecticlight.co/tag/gatekeeper/